# Using list of numbers as function parameter for finding product

Tags: python, list, python-3.5

Alright, I need to write a function `multiplyNums` that takes a list of numbers as a parameter and finds their product. From my reading I think I'm supposed to use *params as my parameter to do this but I have no idea how to actually make it work.

I plan on doing something like this

```
def multiplyNums(*insert said list*)
     for num in said list:
          Use a product operator 
     print (product)
```

If I could get an example of a code that uses a list as a parameter that'd be fantastic, I'm just getting frustrated as I can't get anything I code to work.